# Perform a segue to a new viewController when clicking the "use photo" button after taking picture with camera iOS 10 (swift 3)

Tags: swift3

I want the user to be taken to a new viewController after clicking "use photo" after taking a picture. However, the segue is never performed. I have attempted this segue by connecting two viewControllers via a manual segue. I have a print statement in my imagePickerController function which is where my segue code is. This print statement prints when I click "use photo", so why is my segue be ignored? I tried this exact same segue code within a "@IBAction func someButton (_sender: UIButton)" and it worked fine? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageTake: UIImageView!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func photoLib(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageTake.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)


}

func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}




func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imageTake.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    print("made it")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "new", sender: self)



}
```

}

Comment: Maybe `"new"` is not the identifier of your segue.

Comment: It is, because when I put the same code in an arbitrary button like "@IBAction func someButton (_sender: UIButton)" it worked

Comment: Does "made it" print?

Comment: Yes it does, every time I click "use photo" after taking a picture

Comment: Okay! So if "made it" prints, then we know the line `performSegue(withIdentifier: "new", sender: self)` is executing. But nothing is happening. Therefore, I am suggesting, there is _no_ segue called `"new"` coming from this view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. You have this:

```
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
// ...
performSegue(withIdentifier: "new", sender: self)
```

Change it to this:

```
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "new", sender: self)
})
```

That way, we don't try to perform the segue until the image picker is in fact completely dismissed.

If *that* doesn't work, then I would have to conclude that there is no such segue as `"new"` coming from this view controller. But you have not shown your storyboard so I can't be certain.

Comment: This was the fix! @matt